# Requesting /admin but return to the same page

Tags: python, django, admin

Hello there i m looking to fix a problem i m working on django right now the issue is that when i try to go to the admin area login it returns me to the same index.html page
my code:

urls.py on main folder

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from first_app import views
urlpatterns = [
    url('',views.index,name="index"),
    url('first_app/',include('first_app.urls')),
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

urls.py on first_app folder

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('',views.index,name="index")
]
```

the views.py on first_app folder

```
def index(request):
    my_dic = {'insert_me':"Hello Jinja"}
    return render(request,'index.html',my_dic)
```

index.html file

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css'%}">
    <title>Django  Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>{{ insert_me}}</p>
    <h1>a picture </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up `path` with `url`, if you are using `Django < 2.0`, then use `url` with regex, like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^first_app/', include('first_app.urls')),
    url(r'^*$', views.index, name='index'),
    ...
]
```

And if you are using `Django >= 2.0`, then use like this:

```
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('first_app/',include('first_app.urls')),
    path('',views.index,name="index"),
]
```

More information can be found in [**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/).